# Equal and not equal operators not working in bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, comparison

I have this function inside a .sh script :

```
prepare_for_test(){
    stopresources;
    initresources;
    if [ "$1" = "--gf" ]; then
            startglassfish;
    fi
    docker ps;
    notify-send "Done!" "You can now test" -t 10000;
 };
```

The script's name's preparefortests.sh. When I run it on bash, passing --gf or "--gf":

```
preparefortests.sh --gf
```

it does not run alias startglassfish, as if that if statement was false.
I even tried to add a check on the parameter:

```
if [ "$1" ] && [ "$1" != "--gf" ]; then
  echo "uknown parameter $1"
fi
```

but it's not working neither, when e.g. I try to run it like:

```
preparefortests.sh hello
```

I'd expect "unknown parameter hello".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[ "$1" ] && [ "$1" != "--gf" ]` works as expected, How are you calling the function `prepare_for_test` inside the script?

Comment: @Fravadona just so -> prepare_for_test. after the closing function }, in a new line

Comment: Remember that you need to pass the positional parameters to the function: `prepare_for_test "$@"`.

Comment: @dan   damn! Such a stupid mistake. That was it ! Thank you both guys!

Answer (score 1):

The comparison statement is correct:

```
if [ "$1" = "--gf" ]; then
        startglassfish;
fi
```

There can be other issue like:

1. Make sure you pass $1 argument, while calling function:
   Write `prepare_for_test $1`
2. The problem might be the alias used. For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions. So either you need to make alias as function and export it or instead use special variable BASH_ALIASES. In your case:

```
if [ "$1" = "--gf" ];then
${BASH_ALIASES[startglassfish]};
fi
```